# Spring Core-Setter Injection

Tags: spring

I need help regarding mechanism of setter injection in Spring 3.0
Following is my code

```
package com.common;
class B{
public B(){}
}

class A{
B b;
public A(){}    
public void setB(B b){
syso("I am in setter of B");
}
}
```

In XML,I have,

```
<bean id="A" class="com.common.A">
<property name="b" ref="B" />
</bean>

<bean id="B" class="com.common.B">
```

Now,my question is, How does spring container knows that it has to inject dependency through setB(B b) method? What if I change name of setter as newSetB(B b)? I hope I have made my doubt clear.

Comment: Why do you not try it?

Comment: @Jens..I tried it. It gives following exception in stack trace.."Invalid property 'b' of bean class [A]: Bean property 'b' is not writable or has an invalid setter method"

Comment: So you have an answer of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you have something like this in your property file

```
<bean id="A" class="com.common.A">
      <property name="b" ref="B" />
</bean>
```

spring container by default searches for setter of that property i.e `setPropertyName()` after invoking a no-argument constructor of that class whose bean is being prepared, and as it confines to JavaSpecification it searches for method named as `setPropertyName()`

You can verify this by chaning the name of method or by removing the method entirely

you will get the exception telling that, `No Public setter found for that particular property`

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The mapping here happens in this way.

Lets say we have following bean

```
<bean id="A" class="com.common.A">
      <property name="testProperty" ref="B" />
</bean>
```

Spring container tries to get set method as setTestProperty(), if not found it will through an error.

Hope it helps - Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

when ever SpringContainer reads the xml file and finds this

```
<bean id="A" class="com.common.A">
    <property name="b" ref="B"/>        
</bean>

<bean id="B" class="com.common.B"/>
```

firstly it creates object for Bean A, after that it initializes the member variables here "public B b", b is member variable for Bean class A, so it **searches** for setter method **setB(B b)** if it finds it sets else **if NO setB(B b) SETTER Method is FOUND (OR) SETTER Method named DIFFERRENTLY ex: newSetB(B b)** it throws exception as

> Invalid property 'b' of bean class [com.common.A]: Bean property 'b' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.

setter methods convention for SpringContainer is setPropertyname()